# What does an empty regexp match in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently studying regular expressions in Ruby and there's one thing that I don't understand:

```
2.3.3 :015 > 'abc'.scan(//)
 => ["", "", "", ""] 
2.3.3 :016 > 'abc'.match(//)
 => #<MatchData "">
```

I know that an empty regex is supposed to match any string, but why does `scan` return four matches in this example? Does it count the start and end of the string and then each 'space' between characters? What's the mechanism behind this result?

Comment: It's basically because : `'abc' == ''+'a'+''+'b'+''+'c'+'' #=> true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression `//` doesn't match any string; it matches any *zero-length* string.

But let's back up. Consider this:

```
"ab".scan(/[a-z]/) # => ["a", "b"]
```

That's easy to understand. `String#scan` starts at index 0 and immediately finds a match, `a`, and adds it to its results array, which is now `["a"]`. Then it advances its internal "cursor" to the first index after the matched text, which happens to be 1, where it again finds a match. Now its results are `["a", "b"]`. Finally, it advances to index 2, which is past the end of the string, so it stops.

Now consider your example:

```
"abc".scan(//)
```

This works the same way—almost. `String#scan` starts at index 0 and immediately finds a match: the zero-length string before `a`. It adds it to its results array, which is now `[""]`. But now we're in trouble. Because the match's length is 0, when `String#scan` advances to the first index after the match, it will still be at index 0. It ought to go into an infinite loop, right?

At this point, the regular expression engine makes an executive decision. Because the previous match's length was zero, rather than fall into an infinite loop it advances the cursor by one character. Now the index is 1, whereupon it finds another match: the zero-length string before `b`. Now its results are `["", ""]`. It advances the cursor by one character again and finds the zero-length string before `c`, and again, where it finds the zero-length string before the end of the string (after the `c`). Its final result, then, is `["", "", "", ""]`.

Here's a handy idiom for debugging `String#scan`:

```
"abc".scan(//) do
  p $~, $~.offset(0)
end
```

`$~` is an alias for `Regexp.last_match`, which returns the [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html) object of the last match. `$~.offset(0)` returns an array containing the indexes of the beginning and end of the match (`$~.offset(1)` would return the beginning and end of the first capture group, and so on). In this case, we get:

```
#<MatchData "">
[0, 0]
#<MatchData "">
[1, 1]
#<MatchData "">
[2, 2]
#<MatchData "">
[3, 3]
```

As you can see, each time it matches an empty string (`""`), the first match is at index 0, and the last match is at index 3 ("after" the last character in the string). Try it on repl.it: https://repl.it/GL3N

You can read more about how different regular expression engines handle zero-length matches at (of course) [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html#advance).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jordan, that's an awesome explanation! Off I go to the website you linked, looks like quite an enlightening reading.